# Breadcrumbs component: passing data between page and layout

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I want to pass the data from page `pages/index.vue` to default layout `layouts/default.vue`. to set the dynamic breadcrumb according to the current page with the custom breadcrumb segment.

I have tried the vue 3 provide and inject option but not working and return always `injection "foo" not found.`. Please share ideas to archive this thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `useState` composable [link](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/state-management). Which is provided by nuxt to share data across components. Or you can use a state management system  like vuex or pinia

From nuxt.com useState is,

> Nuxt provides useState composable to create a reactive and SSR-friendly shared state across components.

You can declare any variable with `useState` like this inside your pages directory

```
<script setup>
const counter = useState('counter', () => Math.round(Math.random() * 1000));
</script>

<template>
  <h1>Index page</h1>
  <div>
    <button @click="counter++">Inc Counter From Index</button>
    <button @click="counter--">Dec Counter From Index</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then you can access that variable using `useState` from your layout like this

```
<script setup>
const counter = useState('counter');
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    Some default layout shared across all pages

    <h3>Counter value from the default layout = {{ counter }}</h3>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

Overall a minimal example are given in stackBliz here [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ymvkkk?file=layouts/default.vue)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am going to try this but can you please help me that what is the preferable `pinia` or nuxt `useState` to save the state across all components?

Comment: If you are using Pinia you may have a Hydration mismatch issue. On the other hand, `useState` is SSR-friendly. So you don't have to think about hydration. If your project needs a state management system use Pinia. Otherwise for simple data sharing across components just use `useState` as the official doc says

Comment: I have used the useState for now if I need more state management functionality I'll integrate the pinia. am I going in the right direction? Thank you for your help on this!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to share data between pages and layouts would be **pinia**.

https://pinia.vuejs.org/

https://pinia.vuejs.org/ssr/nuxt.html

You'll create a store (e.g. `stores/breadcrumbs.ts`):

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useBreadcrumbsStore = defineStore('Breadcrumbs', () => {
    const title = ref('')
    // include any data you want
    return {
        title,
    }
})
```

then change the data in `pages/index.vue`

```
...
<script setup>
import { useBreadcrumbsStore } from '~/stores/breadcrumbs.ts'

const breadcrumbsStore = useBreadcrumbsStore()
// change the data
breadcrumbsStore.title = 'Some title'
</script>
```

and use it in your `layouts/default.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    Title: {{ breadcrumbsStore.title }}<hr>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useBreadcrumbsStore } from '~/stores/breadcrumbs.ts'
const breadcrumbsStore = useBreadcrumbsStore()
</script>
```

One thing to note here though - it will cause a **Hydration text mismatch warning**, so the title won't be rendered during SSR.
You can get rid of the warning by wrapping it with *ClientOnly* tag like `<ClientOnly>{{ breadcrumbsStore.title }}</ClientOnly>`, but it won't solve the SSR issue.